# The product of cauchy sequences in the mean is a cauchy sequence in the mean

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I want to see that if $\{f_n\}, \{g_n\}$ are sequences of integrable functions, both Cauchy in the mean (with respect to measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, respectively), then the product sequence $\{f_n g_n \}$ is Cauchy in the mean (with respect to the product measure $\mu \times \nu$). I rewrite $f_n g_n - f_m g_m$ as usual:

$$f_n g_n - f_m g_m = f_n g_n - f_m g_m + f_m g_n - f_m g_n \\ = f_m(g_n - g_m) + g_n(f_n - f_m),$$

so taking absolute values gives

$$\vert f_n g_n - f_m g_m \vert \leq \vert f_m \vert \vert g_n - g_m \vert + \vert g_n \vert \vert f_n - f_m \vert.$$

Now I want to integrate to use the Cauchy-ness of $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$ with their respective measures. But I can't separate the measures to avoid the product. Am I on the right track, and is the statement even true in the first place? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you deduce $|f_{n} g_{n} - f_{m} g_{m}| \leq |f_{m}| |g_{n} - g_{m}| + |g_{m}| |f_{n} - f_{m}|$, take expectations with respect to $\mu \otimes \nu$ to obtain
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(|f_{n}g_{n} - f_{m} g_{m}|) &= \int_{X \times Y} |f_{n}(x) g_{n}(y) - f_{m}(x)g_{m}(y)| \, \mu(dx) \nu(dy) \\
&\leq \int_{X \times Y}\left[|f_{m}(x)| |g_{n}(y) - g_{m}(y)| + |g_{n}(y)| |f_{n}(x) - f_{m}(x)| \right]\, \mu(dx) \nu(dy) \\
&= \int_{X} |f_{m}(x)| \, \mu(dx) \cdot \int_{Y} |g_{n}(y) - g_{m}(y)| \, \nu(dy) + \int_{Y} |g_{n}(y)| \, \nu(dy) \cdot \int_{X} |f_{n}(x) - f_{m}(x)| \, \mu(dx) \\
&= \mathbb{E}(|f_{m}|) \mathbb{E}(|g_{n} - g_{m}|) + \mathbb{E}(|g_{n}|) \mathbb{E}(|f_{n} - f_{m}|).
\end{align*}
Above I used the Fubini-Tonelli theorem.  Now the sequences $(\mathbb{E}(|f_{n}|))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(\mathbb{E}(|g_{n}|))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are both bounded, by the "Cauchy in the mean" assumption.  Thus, the fact that $\mathbb{E}(|g_{n} - g_{m}|), \mathbb{E}(|f_{n} - f_{m}|) \to 0$ as $n,m \to \infty$ implies the same for $\mathbb{E}(|f_{n} g_{n} - f_{m} g_{m}|)$.